# Accelerometer always return 0 and is not available. Ligbdx, Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, accelerometer

i'm new in java programming (especially with libgdx library).
I'm trying to developing a simply android game that use the movement of the smartphone for moving an object on the screen.
The object is really simple cuz got 2 coordinates (x,y) and with the accelerometer i want to update the coordinates.

stringstamp is used to understand if Accelerometer is available;

in the manifest i put :

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="true" />
```

this is the code:

```
public void Ball_isMoving(){

    tmpx=x;
    tmpy=y;

    if(Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer)){
        accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
        accelY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
        stringstamp = "ok";
    }
    else {
        stringstamp = "no";
    }

    if (accelX < -1){
        tmpx-=accelY*200*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    if (accelY < -1 ){
        tmpy-=accelX*200*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    if (accelX > +1 ){
        tmpx+=accelY*200*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    if (accelY > +1){
        tmpy+=accelX*200*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    if(tmpx>-1 && tmpx<Gdx.graphics.getWidth())
        x=tmpx;

    if(tmpy>-1 && tmpy<Gdx.graphics.getHeight())
        y=tmpy;

}
```

Comment: Its may true, are you sure that tour device has accelerometer?

Comment: I tried on htc one m7 and on Samsung s6. I should try with get roll()???